# different content while accessing subdomain and the same directory under main domain

Tags: javascript, html, css, cpanel

So, the topic name is somewhat weird, and as so the problem is...

We were building a web portal for hosting a competition.
The server we use has centos 7.9.2009 (Core), with whmcs, Cpanel, and light speed web server.

Problem:
On making a subdomain from Cpanel it creates a subdomain folder for that subdomain inside public_html (which is actually pointed by the main domain)

So theoretically I should get the same content with subdomain.domain.tld and domain.tld/subdomain    (unless external rules are written and applied)

[project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yHrO.png)

Here are the link: https://fizika.gramoly.org/ and https://gramoly.org/fizika/

[Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcxkW.png)

You can clearly see the wrong area....

If we are accessing the same directory but with different methods then why are we getting different outputs. Also, it's just using normal HTML, CSS, and js.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Without looking, I'm going to bet that the problem is caused by the use of `/` at the front of a URL, so you should make sure you understand what that actually means.

Comment: How can I reproduce a error which I am not able to figure out why happening. I mean its not happening because of code. Code is same. But when I access the same file https://fizika.gramoly.org/ it shows some errors in displaying the content while it works fine when accessed over https://gramoly.org/fizika/

Comment: If you can't break the problem down into a [mcve] then Stackoverflow may simply be an inappropriate place to seek help for your problem.

Comment: yeah but please understand the situation. You also know that it's not being cause by code. also there isn't any .htaccess specified. its just plain simple HTML, css and js. same dir. just accessing through different way. one through subdomain and one through normal subdir pointing. I am really dumbstruck rn as I can't find what's the problem. please throw some light on what possible things should I try to fix this as I am clueless and tried numerous things like deleting the subdomain and creating another and pasting the files there. Still the same error :(